# How to remove all versions of a formula with brew

Tags: homebrew

```
$ brew remove hadoop
Error: hadoop has multiple installed versions
```

I can not seem to find a way how to remove all the versions (they are `1.0.4` and `1.1.2`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`brew cleanup hadoop` seems to be the way to go, it uninstalls all the versions installed! Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: actually, **brew cleanup FORMULA** delete all but the newer version :-)

Answer (score 23):

This also seems to work:

```
brew remove --force hadoop
```